# Solving a functional equation over the real number line

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all functions $f : R \to  R$ which satisfy $$f(x)f(y) = f(xy) + xy$$

Comment: Gosh. Where are the workings ?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please show some of your working, as it means that people can make sure their answer is at your level of knowledge and doesn't cover things you already know

Comment: Try putting in numbers? For example $x=1,y=1$ give us $$f(1)f(1)=f(1\times 1)+1\times 1 = f(1)+1$$

Comment: Show your work then  we can function.

Comment: Problems of this kind are often called "functional equations".  A more specific title would help interested Readers find your post and (perhaps) give you some ideas about earlier related posts on Math.SE.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=1$, we have
$$f(x)f(1)=f(x)+x$$
$$(f(1)-1)f(x)=x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{f(1)-1}$$

So let
$$f(x)=Ax$$
we have
$$AxAy=Axy+xy$$
$$A^2-A-1=0$$
$$A=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}x$$